# Hours and time converting to a certain format

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, timedelta

I have been trying to change the following format of time `8.25 (fractional hours)` to `8.15 meaning 8:15`. And `17.75` to `17.45 meaning 17:45`. The problem is that I specifically need that format (timedelta) `e.g 17.45` with a point `.` instead of `:`.

Comment: Hint: `60 * .75 = 45`…

Comment: Removed `pandas` tag as it is irrelevant.

Comment: The question is unclear about the type of all the literals. It's telling us something about a *format* but instead only shows confusing examples.

Comment: @Wolf: I think the point here is that a number like `17.75` is not a *time format* but fractional hours, namely a *duration* (to be represented by a `timedelta` in Python). I posted a way how to do this on Dave's [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66141034/10197418).

Comment: @MrFuppes Maybe, but it could also be some string

Comment: @Wolf: why would the datatype matter? you could convert to float in that case. Anyways, I'd avoid representing date & time like that, just too confusing ^^

Comment: Wouldn't it be much less confusing to integrate [your follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66140155/2932052) here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done conveniently by using the appropriate representation for your fractional hours, namely a `timedelta`. If the input is of datatype string, convert to float first.

**Ex:**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

for td in [8.25, 17.75]:
    # add the duration as timedelta to an arbitrary date to get a time object:
    print((datetime(2020,1,1) + timedelta(hours=td)).time())
```

```
08:15:00
17:45:00
```

Using `pandas`, that could look like

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([8.25, 17.75])

refDate = '2020-01-01' # need a date..

t = pd.Timestamp(refDate) + pd.to_timedelta(s, unit='h')

print(t)

# 0   2020-01-01 08:15:00
# 1   2020-01-01 17:45:00
# dtype: datetime64[ns]

print(t.dt.time)

# 0    08:15:00
# 1    17:45:00
# dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your string of format `HH.MM`, you can approach it as follows:

```
my_time = "17.75"
hours, minutes = my_time.split(".")  # (17, 75)
minutes_converted = round(float(minutes) / 100 * 60)  # 45
my_time_converted = "{}.{}".format(hours, minutes_converted)  #17.45
print(my_time_converted)

> 17.45
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works porperly but the thing now is I would need the other format as well such as ```17:45``` not only ```17.45```. I tried to modify the code above but it did not work either. Given that that value in ```my_time = "17.75"``` is only in that form.

Comment: @Dave You literally just need to change `{}.{}` to `{}:{}` in the above code…

Comment: @deceze OP believes to want both? ... a really confusing (and frustrating) case where we are denied the really informative details!