# Converting float into datatime64[ns]

Tags: python, datetime

This question is related to the following one here [Hours and time converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66137870/hours-and-time-converting)

I have got the following array with the corresponding values form the previous question:

```
a = [[7.15, 7.45, 9.30, 10.45, 13.45, 15.15, 15.45, 21.30]]
```

its values are floats and they represent hours of a day, e.g. `7.15` is equal to `7:15`. Now I am using the following formula to in pandas to make a comaprison:

```
df.loc[([df['orders_time'] >= a[0]) & (df['orders_time'] <= a[1]), 'new_time'] = 10
```

It returns an error saying:

```
Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and float64
```

I tried to change the format of the values in `a` I was not able to run it.

Comment: The question stated that 7.25 would represent 7.15. I read it.

Comment: Than the statement " its values are floats and they represent hours" must be corrected. It's a special format that deserves much more explanation. What about `7.88`? What about `7.155`?

Comment: I gave these numbers as to show you that your float values ***don't represent hours*** -- to me it seems obvious that they are not even float.For comparing it with datetime values you ***have to convert*** them into normal floats (e.g. `"7.15"` -> `7.25`), else you will cause very ugly errors at runtime just *because* it doesn't crash.

Comment: I think you can just convert the floats to datetime with the correct format string.  Something like `pd.to_datetime(df['orders_time], format = '%H.%S').time()`

Comment: Your code snippets contradict each other: first you tell us that `a` is a `list` with a `list` in it, next you tell us that you get a float from `a[0]`. Please fix it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `a` into a list of times.

```
a = [pd.to_datetime(i, format = '%H.%M').time() for i in a[0]]
```

then you can compare time to time using:

```
df.loc[([df['orders_time'].dt.time >= a[0]) & (df['orders_time'].dt.time <= a[1]), 'new_time'] = 10
```

Comment: format='%H.%M' I think - but if you have a look at the OP's other question, this is not necessary in the first place.

Comment: Maybe it's time to remove/replace above comment now?

Comment: @Wolf Thank you very much for your comments. I tried to remove the ban, but it is valid. Could you please help me or give me some tipps to remove it? Thank you!

Comment: @DaveWill sorry, I don't understand what you are referring to, what do you mean by ban?